# how can I clean a prefinished door?

Tags: doors

I have a prefinished bedroom door and it appears to have developed a grey patch that looks like grease.  The patch isn't grease, however it just appeared by itself. Any help as to how I can get clean it off?

Comment: Do you have pets? Any explanation at all as how it got there? Usually discoloration happens for a reason. Is the location damp? maybe it is mildew....

Comment: I wouldn't mess with a magic door.

Answer (score 4):

I would try, in order of escalating cleaning function, these series of things until a suitable result has been obtained:

- Wiping with a clean dry cloth.
- Apply a little (15 ml/1 Tbsp) white vinegar to a paper towel and wipe.  Rinse with a wet (water) paper towel.
- Combined with vinegar or dish detergent (for hand washing), use a rough cloth or mild scrub brush (pink or white Scotch brite).
- Green Scotch bright and soap.  Repainting might be necessary afterward.
- 220 grit sandpaper
- 150 grit sandpaper
- 100 grit sandpaper
- woodworking plane
- replace the door

Comment: You forgot *move out*